# Get Successive Login of a user in wordpress in Days

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a code to be able to get the Successive Login of a user in WordPress in Days and when the user didn't login in a day it will reset to 0 days

https://www.screencast.com/t/mu28LtiD

Answer (score 0):

Already have an answer to my question.

using a shortcode and funtions.php

```
            function successive_logins( $atts ) {

            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;

            $today = date("d.m.Y");
            $yesterday = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));

            $login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
            if (isset($login)){
                if ($login == $yesterday){
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                    $day = get_user_meta($user_id, 'successive_logins_days', true);
                    $day = $day + 1;
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $day);
                    return $day;
                } 
                elseif ($login == $today){      
                    return get_user_meta($user_id, 'successive_logins_days', true);
                }
                else {
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                    $first_day = 1;
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $first_day);
                    return $first_day;
                }
            } else {
                add_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                $first_day = 1;
                add_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $first_day);
                return $first_day;
            }

                } else {
                   return '1'; 
                }
            }
            add_shortcode( 'get_login_meta', 'successive_logins');


            // for updating only entering website
            function successive_logins_update( $atts ) {

            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            $today = date("d.m.Y");
            $yesterday = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
            $login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
            if (isset($login)){
                if ($login == $yesterday){
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                    $day = get_user_meta($user_id, 'successive_logins_days', true);
                    $day = $day + 1;
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $day);
                    return '';
                } 
                elseif ($login == $today){      
                    return '';
                }
                else {
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                    $first_day = 1;
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $first_day);
                    return '';
                }
            } else {
                add_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_login', $today);
                $first_day = 1;
                add_user_meta( $user_id, 'successive_logins_days', $first_day);
                return '';
            }
                } else {
                   return ''; 
                }
            }
            successive_logins_update();
```